# Order of integration - improper integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

> **Problem:** Express the integrals in the opposite order.
>   $$(a) \quad \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^{\infty} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy$$
>   $$(b) \quad \int_{-\infty}^0 \int_0^{y^2} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy$$
>   $$(c) \quad \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^x f(x,y) \, dy \, dx$$

**Solution:**
$$(a) \ \ \int_{0}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y) \, dy \, dx\quad (b) \ \ \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\sqrt{x}} f(x,y) \, dy \, dx\quad (c) \ \ \int_{0}^\infty \int_y^\infty f(x,y) \, dx \, dy$$

Are my solutions correct? Thanks.

Comment: I think you want $\int_{-\infty}^{\boxed{-}\sqrt{x}}$ in $(b)$. Note that $y\le0$ in the original integral.

Comment: Yeah that's true, I got confused, Thanks!

Comment: Also $(c)$ is incorrect. You seem to assume that $y\ge0$.

Comment: What happened to the $-\infty < x < 0$  part of the region in c)?

Comment: I thought $y \geq 0$ because the region is bounded by $x$-axis from below?

Comment: What is the correct solution for $(c)$?